# Selenium+Рython:дождитесь исчезновения веб-элемента

Tags: python, selenium

Начал осваивать Selenium.В общем виде задача такая: На странице есть кнопка нужно подождать когда кнопка исчезнет после того как кнопка исчезла нужно подождать 30 минут и после чего кликнуть по кнопке.
Подскажите как реализовать задание, т.к. моих знаний в Selenium пока не хватает для решения.

```
import datetime,timedelta
data = datetime.datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=30)
t=datetime.datetime.now()


while True:
    element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("div[@class='one-business '][1]/div[@class='business-party']/button[@class='btn lobby-item__button lobby-item__view']")
    size = len(element)
    if len(element) > 0:
        sleep(1)
    else:
        if(data!=t):
            element.click()
```

Comment: Подождать 30 мин перед кликом можно вот так:

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1800)

Comment: Добавил импорт всех модулей библиотеки, которые Вам нужны

Answer (score 0):

Подождать 30 мин перед кликом можно вот так:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1800)
```